# Setting params on useEffect and getting the params it on createStackNav in React Navigation 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am working on an app where in I need to send or set a particular params of my state in an object.

Here's my object with its respected state:

```
   const [isGlutenFree, setIsGlutenFree] = useState(false);
    const [isLactoseFree, setisLactoseFree] = useState(false);
    const [isVegan, setIsVegan] = useState(false);
    const [isVegetarian, setIsVegetarian] = useState(false);
    
    const saveFilters = () => {
       const appliedFilters = {
          glutenFree: isGlutenFree,
          lactosFree: isLactoseFree,
          vegan: isVegan,
          isVegetarian: isVegetarian
       };
    };
```

These are all sitting on my `FiltersScreen.js` file. So on my `useEffect` I tried to use the [CommonActions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#setparams) to set the params:

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

useEffect(() => {
    props.navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.setParams({ save: saveFilters }));
});
```

Then inside my `Navigator.js` file, I tried to receive this and console.log this on the screen to see that it has the data I need:

```
<FilterNav.Screen
                name="Filters"
                component={FiltersScreen}
                options={({ route }) => ({
                    title: 'Filters',
                    headerLeft: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Menu'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.toggleDrawer();
                                }}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    ),
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Save'
                                iconName='ios-save'
                                onPress={() => {
                                    // CONSOLE LOG THE PARAMS SET >>
                                    console.log(route.params.save);
                                }}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    )
                })}

            />
        </FilterNav.Navigator>
```

To be specific on this part:

```
 headerRight: () => (
                            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                                <Item
                                    title='Save'
                                    iconName='ios-save'
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        // CONSOLE LOG THE PARAMS SET >>
                                        console.log(route.params.save);
                                    }}
                                />
                            </HeaderButtons>
                        )
```

But this doesn't work and doesn't return anything. Also it freezes all of my Switches.

Here's the complete code for `FiltersScreen.js`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Switch, Platform } from 'react-native';

import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

import Colors from '../constants/colors';

const FiltersSwitch = props => {
    return(
    <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
        <Text>{ props.label }</Text>
        <Switch
            trackColor={{ true: Colors.primaryColor }}
            thumbColor={Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primaryColor : ''}
            value={props.state}
            onValueChange={props.onChange} />
    </View>
    );
};

const FiltersScreen = props => {

    const [isGlutenFree, setIsGlutenFree] = useState(false);
    const [isLactoseFree, setisLactoseFree] = useState(false);
    const [isVegan, setIsVegan] = useState(false);
    const [isVegetarian, setIsVegetarian] = useState(false);
    
    // We will give this a connection with the 
    // MealsNavigator in order to trigger this 
    // function via useEffect 
    const saveFilters = () => {
       const appliedFilters = {
          glutenFree: isGlutenFree,
          lactosFree: isLactoseFree,
          vegan: isVegan,
          isVegetarian: isVegetarian
       };
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        props.navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.setParams({ save: saveFilters }));
    });

    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Available Filters / Restrictions</Text>
            <FiltersSwitch
                label="Glutten Free"
                state={isGlutenFree}
                onChange={newValue => setIsGlutenFree(newValue)} />

            <FiltersSwitch
                label="Lactose Free"
                state={isLactoseFree}
                onChange={newValue => setisLactoseFree(newValue)} />

            <FiltersSwitch
                label="Vegan"
                state={isVegan}
                onChange={newValue => setIsVegan(newValue)} />

            <FiltersSwitch
                label="Vegetarian"
                state={isVegetarian}
                onChange={newValue => setIsVegetarian(newValue)} />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    title: {
        fontFamily: 'poppins-bold',
        fontSize: 22,
        margin: 20,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    filterContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '80%',
        marginVertical: 15
    }
});

export default FiltersScreen;
```

And here's the complete code for the `navigation.js` file:

```
const FilterNav = createStackNavigator();

const FiltersNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <FilterNav.Navigator
            mode="modal"
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}
        >
            <FilterNav.Screen
                name="Filters"
                component={FiltersScreen}
                options={({ route }) => ({
                    title: 'Filters',
                    headerLeft: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Menu'
                                iconName='ios-menu'
                                onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.toggleDrawer();
                                }}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    ),
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Save'
                                iconName='ios-save'
                                onPress={() => {
                                    console.log(route.params.save);
                                }}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    )
                })}

            />
        </FilterNav.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Please help how to solve this been stuck for a couple of time. I am using React Navigation 5.

Comment: In `FiltersScreen.js` can you please try to use `props.navigation.setParams({ save: saveFilters });` and tell if it works? Also, do your `useEffect` have an dependency array? It should, I don't know if you just removed to post the code here

Comment: It doesn't do anything. At the top of that, it freezes my screen of FiltersScreen, i can't touch anything at all. As per the dependency its an object of states as seen above.

Comment: Your `saveFilters` is a function but it does nothing, just creates an object. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the "freeze" problem is that your `useEffect` is executing in every screen render, since it has no dependency array (read [Tip: Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)).

Your code should look something like this:

```
// useCallback, so it doesn't create a new saveFilters function in every render
const saveFilters = useCallback(() => {
  const appliedFilters = {
    glutenFree: isGlutenFree,
    lactosFree: isLactoseFree,
    vegan: isVegan,
    isVegetarian: isVegetarian
  };
}, [isGlutenFree, isLactoseFree, isVegan, isVegetarian]); // This function depends on those variables.

useEffect(() => {
  props.navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.setParams({ save: saveFilters }));
}, [saveFilters]); // It should change the parameterized function if it changes
```